# How to navigate to another tab's screen using material-bottom-tabs (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, material-design

my react native app has a number of screens and my problem is, that I need to access (direct link) to another Tab's screen. So far, when I navigate to another tab's screen, the bottom navigation active index/state doesn't change. How can I achieve to navigate to another tab's screen and correctly set the new screen's bottom navigation icon to active?

**Example:** I use this code on the Dashboard tab and need to change to tab B which hosts screen B. This works so far, but the active state of the material-bottom-tabs doesn't change.

```
navigation.navigate( 'screenb_tab' )
```

- **Login** (if Login succesfully, go to Main-Area)
- **Main** (shows material-bottom-tabs):

  - **Dashboard**
  - **Screen B**

    - has **sub-screen**: BSubScreen

Therefore I setup the following files:
**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './mainComponents/login/index';
import BottomTab from './mainComponents/navigation/bottomTab';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
      <MProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" headerMode='none'>
            <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={BottomTab} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </MProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**bottomTab.js**

```
// https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/
import * as React from 'react';
import Dashboard from '../dashboard/index';
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

function BottomNavigationConfig(props) {
  const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
  const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator();
  const ScreenBStack = createStackNavigator();


  function DashboardTab() {
    return  <DashboardStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
                <DashboardStack.Screen name="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <DashboardStack.Screen name="screenb_tab" component={ScreenBTab} />
             </DashboardStack.Navigator>
  }

  function ScreenBTab() {
    return <ScreenBStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
              <ScreenBStack.Screen name="screenb_home" component={ScreenBHome} />
              <ScreenBStack.Screen name="screenb_subscreen" component={ScreenBSubscreen} />
            </ScreenBStack.Navigator>
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="dashboard_tab">
      <Tab.Screen name="dashboard_tab" component={DashboardTab} options={ { title: 'Dashboard', tabBarIcon: 'view-dashboard'} } />
      <Tab.Screen name="screenb_tab" component={ScreenBTab} options={ { title: 'Screen B', tabBarIcon: 'factory'} } />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default BottomNavigationConfig;
```

I think I somehow don't get how navigating between tabs and stacks works. I tried to figure this out for 8 hours and had no luck. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: navigation.navigate("navigatorName",{screen: "screenName"}) is used to navigate between screens in different stacks.
Take a look here: https://www.reactnativeschool.com/master-react-navigation-v5/

Comment: @ErikDreifaldt nice - thank you so much :)